# RDBMS web service

Tags: http, service, rdbms, sqlanywhere

I guess my heading is wrong, sorry for that.

In SQL Anywhere, there is an option to create a service that handles HTTP requests from clients and returns documents in HTML format. This implies that the whole application resides in the database, and you can feed views etc. to just a browser.

My question is, is there an implementation on other RDBMS's to create something similar to this, without writing any code in other programming/scripting language? I have been investigating Oracle and SQL Servers Native XML web Services, but they only support SOAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, no other RDBMS servers have this capability. I know Sybase has a [patent](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect2=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&d=PALL&RefSrch=yes&Query=PN/7448047) on the idea.

*Full disclosure: I work for Sybase in SQL Anywhere engineering. My name is one of the names on the patent.*